# Error message while submitting Google Cloud ML Training job for Tensorflow Object Detection

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

Trying to submit a Google Cloud ML Training job for Tensorflow Object Detection task and I am following the [official guideline](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md)

Following is the job that I am submitting:

```
export CONFIG=trainer/cloud.yaml
export TRAIN_DIR=kt-1000/training
export PIPELINE_CONFIG=kt-1000/training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config

gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training object_detection_`date +%s` \
```

```
    --job-dir=gs://${TRAIN_DIR} \
    --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim
0.1.tar.gz \
    --module-name object_detection.train \
    --region asia-east1-a \
    --config ${CONFIG} \
    -- \
    --train_dir=gs://${TRAIN_DIR} \
    --pipeline_config_path=gs://${PIPELINE_CONFIG}
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) unrecognized arguments:
```

The Error message however does not point out which argument/s is unrecognised though!!!!

Any help on this will be truly appreciated

Thanks,

Devjothi

Comment: Try to remove the space(s) after the "\" in the each line?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to remove any space before `--`, like this:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
--job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH \
--runtime-version 1.10  \
--python-version 3.5 \
--module-name trainer.task \
--package-path trainer/ \
--region $REGION \
-- \
--train-files $TRAIN_DATA \
--eval-files $EVAL_DATA \
--train-steps 1000 \
--eval-steps 100 \
--verbosity DEBUG
```

Comment: That was precisely my problem and it should be the accepted answer. I'm used to adding spaces in script files to help with readability which led to the error

Answer (score 1):

I met the problems as well with the official guideline on my windows machine.

1.Check what is the unrecognized arguments.

2.Beware of between `--config` and `--train_dir` there is an empty `--` (that was my error came from)

ps: on windows there is no `date +%s`. Therefore, I replace by my own JOB_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the job-dir. You don't need to specify job-dir.  ML Engine will pass in a job-dir when it invokes your job

Comment: :I took out job-dir but still getting the same message. Will request if someone from Google Cloud ML team can take a look at this and respond back. Please note that I have followed the same steps as mentioned in the Google Cloud ML documentation in Github

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i added the following

```
import gcsfs
```

then the $ variables are recognized.