# Error: "argument --job-dir: expected one argument" while training model using AI Platform on GCP

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Running macOS Mojave.

I am following the [official getting started documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-keras) to run a model using AI platform.

So far I managed to train my model locally using:

```
# This is similar to `python -m trainer.task --job-dir local-training-output`
# but it better replicates the AI Platform environment, especially
# for distributed training (not applicable here).
gcloud ai-platform local train \
  --package-path trainer \
  --module-name trainer.task \
  --job-dir local-training-output
```

I then proceed to train the model using AI platform by going through the following steps:

1. Setting environment variables `export JOB_NAME="my_first_keras_job"` and `export JOB_DIR="gs://$BUCKET_NAME/keras-job-dir"`.
2. Run the following command to package the `trainer/` directory:

Command as indicated in docs:

```
 gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
   --package-path trainer/ \
   --module-name trainer.task \
   --region $REGION \
   --python-version 3.5 \
   --runtime-version 1.13 \
   --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
   --stream-logs
```

I get the error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.jobs.submit.training) argument --job-dir:
>   expected one argument Usage: gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training
>   JOB [optional flags] [-- USER_ARGS ...]   optional flags may be 
>   --async | --config | --help | --job-dir | --labels | ...

As far as I understand `--job-dir:` does indeed have one argument.

---

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am running the above command from the `trainer/` directory as is shown in the documentation. I tried removing all spaces as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000556/error-message-while-submitting-google-cloud-ml-training-job-for-tensorflow-objec) but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this command locally? Or on a AI notebook VM in Jupyter? Based on your details I assume youre running it locally, I am not a mac expert, but hopefully this is helpful.

I just worked through the same error on an AI notebook VM and my issue was that even though I assigned it a value in a previous Jupyter cell, the ***$JOB_NAME*** variable was passing along an empty string in the gcloud command. Try running the following to make sure your code is actually passing a value for $JOB_DIR when you are making the ***gcloud ai-platform*** call.

```
echo $JOB_DIR
```